# iPhone app with Territory Limitation

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, country

Currently I have a live iPhone app. I need to convert it to a paid one with territory limitations. That means I need to make my app paid for some territories and free for the rest.

1. Will apple allow this?
2. Can I upload 2 separate apps with same features, one is free and other is paid but their no feature changes. Only territory limitations.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you can not change price of the same Application for different territory. Apple will not allow to do so. In fact there is no such option to set different price for different territory.

So for the second you mentioned **i say YES**. To do so you to keep few things in mind.

- Let say you have created 2 different applications with same features for 2 different countries with different price tags
- Make sure the version which you uploaded for **Country-A** should be only visible to **Country-A**. And same for **Country-B**.
- Keep Description & keywords localized language.
- Make sure there is something different in both app versions. Otherwise Apple team will feel its a similar concept & they might reject the application.

Hope it will guide you.

Comment: there should be some difference in 2 applications...right ?

Comment: @AbhijithG just to make sure don't taking any risk. As you know apple might reject.